# Excel refresh of SQL Query to also refresh set of values

Tags: sql, excel

I have a spreadsheet that gets information from a SQL Server and populates it into Sheet2. 
In Sheet 1, the first 4 rows of information are to be updated when a Refresh is done.

So basically, I need a way for the refresh to update what is in Sheet1 with the new information it gets from the database in Sheet2.

The reason I do not just have the Query populate into Sheet1 and just hide all the extra info is because the users will need to insert rows into Sheet1. Since the SQL data is always put into a table, it does not allow inserting of rows. For that same reason, I can't use something like =INDEX(Sheet2 A:A, ROW(), COLUMN()). (Also, for various reasons, macros are not an option).

The way I am handling it now, I need to do the refresh, then copy and paste the information into Sheet1. I am hoping there is an automatic way of doing this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What ever you can do manually in Excel, you can also automate with a macro.  The macro recorder is a good way to get started.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to mention that I can't use macros for this.